# Multiple select SQL in one table

Tags: mysql

I have table proctcategory. For example:

```
**id-idParent-name**  
1-0-Screen
2-1-15.6
...
```

Now I have two SQL query:

```
$id=1;
$query="SELECT name FROM `productcategory` WHERE id=".$id;
```

and

```
$query="SELECT id FROM `productcategory` WHERE idParent=".$id;
```

Can I make one query for this problem? Thanks

Comment: use union of the first and the second query

Comment: Is this what your looking for?  $query = "SELECT name FROM productcategory WHERE id=".$id.
               UNION
              SELECT name FROM productcategory WHERE idParent=".$id ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT name, id FROM productcategory WHERE id=".$id." OR idParent=".$id.";
```

Edited one:
a) for id and idParent to be same
    $id = '1';//For many $id = '1,2,3'

```
$query = "SELECT name, id FROM productcategory WHERE id=idParent AND id IN(".$id.");
```

b) for id and idParent may or may not be same

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(id), name FROM productcategory WHERE idParent IN(".$id.") OR id IN(".$id.") ";
```

Will this solve your question?

Comment: That should be a `AND` condition rather!

Comment: Thanks. Rahul. If he needs the row like id-idParent-name as 1-1-abc. Then he can replace OR with AND.

Comment: Yes, but I need only one row with name and only one with id. In this case, I can't know what is the name of id=1 and id of idParent=1. I will get two or more rows with name and id. Example: screen,1  -- 15.6,2 --- ...

Comment: so u want only one row with id and idParent both as 1 like 1-1-aaa? right?

Comment: @MilosPopovic , maybe you could give an example in your original post. Btw, you do know the diffrence between a row and a column do you?